# Backbone Mongoid Rails set up will not let me update a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, mongoid

Can someone help me understand how to make [Ryan Bate's screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1?view=comments) on Backbone.js work with MongoDB as my database while using the Mongoid gem.

This is what I am seeing.

When I create a new entry via the console, similar to how Ryan did it in the video with `entry.create`, Rails adds that entry just fine. Below is my Ruby log and my JavaScript headers log from Chrome Inspector.

### Ruby Log

```
Started POST "/api/entries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-12 17:31:24 -0600
Processing by EntriesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"name"=>"Heather", "entry"=>{"name"=>"Heather", "action"=>"create",         "controller"=>"entries"}}
MONGODB w_market_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB           w_market_development['entries'].insert([{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f384bcc504b9348be000003'),     "name"=>"Heather"}])
Completed 201 Created in 11ms (Views: 2.4ms)
```

### Headers Log

```
Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/entries
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Request Headers (14)
Request Payload
{"name":"Heather"}
```

As you can see it posted fine. Now let me show you an update via the `entry.save()` example Ryan showed us.

### Ruby Log

```
Started POST "/api/entries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-12 17:34:25 -0600
Processing by EntriesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"_id"=>"4f38152c504b9345dc000005", "name"=>"Bloip", "winner"=>true,     "entry"=>{"_id"=>"4f38152c504b9345dc000005", "name"=>"Bloip", "winner"=>true,     "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"entries"}}
MONGODB w_market_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB     w_market_development['entries'].insert([{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f38152c504b9345dc000005'),     "name"=>"Bloip", "winner"=>true}])
Completed 201 Created in 12ms (Views: 2.7ms)
```

### Headers Log

```
Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/entries
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Request Headers (14)
Request Payload
{"_id":"4f38152c504b9345dc000005","name":"Bloip","winner":true}
```

---

As you can see when I complete the `entry.save()` on a current entry, which should be an update, the JSON is showing a POST instead of a PUT, which Mongoid is doing nothing with and the DB shows no changes. After Googling I found the following articles but nothing really helped.

https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/issues/8
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/17/making-mongoid-play-nice-with-backbone-js/

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same object? Could you post a code example that produces the same problem?

Comment: What files should I post code from?

Comment: So I finally got it to PUT instead of POST. I had to reference my backbone.js model in the Backbone.js collection file. However, now I am running into another issue. My PUT Json looks like the following:                        Parameters: {"_id"=>"4f40101f504b9361a5000001", "id"=>"4f40101f504b9361a5000001", "name"=>"Blup", "winner"=>true, "entry"=>{"_id"=>"4f40101f504b9361a5000001", "id"=>"4f40101f504b9361a5000001", "name"=>"Blup", "winner"=>true, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"entries"}} and it is not saving anything on the mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was going through the RailsCast as described above. I was using the entries controller that Ryan put together. After much searching, copying, pasting, and retrying I found that I need a completely new Controller set up. Below is what I originally had.

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Entry.all
  end

  def show
    respond_with Entry.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    respond_with Entry.create(params[:entry])
  end

  def update
    respond_with Entry.update(params[:id], params[:entry])
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Entry.destroy(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is the Controller code the fixed the issue for me.

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
      render :json => Entry.all
    end

    def show
      render :json => Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      entry = Entry.create! params
      render :json => entry
    end

    def update
      entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
      entry.update_attributes!(params[:entry])
      render :json => entry
    end

    def destroy
      render :json => Entry.destroy(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

Thanks All!

Travis